# Pull data from a datagrid and display them on checkboxes within a combobox in WPF

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

Please am new to WPF and am creating an application in which a user can select multiple items via checkboxes within a combobox. The items on the checkboxes are subject to change so, i want to add an editable datagrid table. Please, my problem now is to make any changes on the datagrid be reflected by the checkboxes. 
I was only to add the checkboxes within the combox with xaml and have finished with the styling but don't know how to go about the codes.

Comment: How are you currently feeding the data to the combobox? Can you show us some code?

Answer (score 1):

Seems to me like what you need is to bind the list of items from the `DataGrid` to the `ComboBox` (let them have binding to the same `DataContext`), and set the `ComboBox`'s `ItemContainerStyle` to display a `CheckBox`.

I don't fully understand what the check of the CheckBox should display, but perhaps it can be data bound to some other property or to the data item itself and use a converter, or it can look at a property of the data item and use Triggers or DataTriggers.

Perhaps if you posted some code we could give a better answer...

Hope it helps.